# How can I kill everything on my Android tablet except my app, and keep them all dead?

Tags: android, background, kill

Please don't tell me what a bad idea this is. I am not using it as an Android tablet. It is the interface for a propitiatory medical system my company is designing. It's only function ever will be to control the system we are building.

That being said, how can I remove everything from the tablet and only run my app until the tablet dies or the standard firmware is reinstalled?

The tablet is being used exclusively as an interface control panel and CPU to my program which controls the medical equipment externally. I don't want anything else on the tablet. I don't want the users to do anything other than run my program on my equipment.

How can I lock the users into only using my program for the life of the tablet?

(I am building a system that happens to use an Android tablet to control it. Basically, I thought it would be easier to use a tablet, rather than design from scratch a system based on one or more microprocessors and which uses a custom designed and built color interface panel. If the doctors want to use an Android tablet for their offices, they are welcome to buy one.)

Thank you in advance.

Thank you all for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to build your own version of Android if you wish to do this. For several reasons it is not possible to make an application that will do what you want and have it work on consumer devices.

Exactly how you need to go about customizing the OS build is going to depend on your exact hardware. But the simplest modifications will be removing the unneeded apk files from `system/app/` and `data/app/`

[AOSP](http://source.android.com/) and [XDA-Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) are two great resources for learning the ins and outs of building a custom ROM.

Answer (score 1):

If the device has reasonable power to it, you shouldn't need to worry about background processes.

If this is a consumer product, then it probably has the Google Apps suite and other related items, in which case rooting it and not installing those would be the best route. AOSP only runs processes that it needs to run Android out of the box.

Edit: You might just write the apps a Launcher and not allow opening other apps as the best route to accomplishing your goals.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a custom ROM.  It really depends on what version of Android your device supports. Check out the last in the list below.

http://www.redmondpie.com/best-most-popular-custom-roms-for-android-and-why-you-should-try-them-out/

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing similar obstacles utilizing my business tablets.  I want to restrict all the pre-loaded applications & only allow the tablet to be utilized for certain applications.  White listed websites & such.  I wonder if a 3rd party service such as ZENPRISE might offer a mobile management system that would take care of this for me?

[zenprise](http://www.zenprise.com/)